# WP Method `get_theme_file_uri()` Doesn't Seem To Be Working Properly When Used In The Head Section Of A Site

Tags: links, template-tags

I'm preloading a web font in the head section of a WP custom theme and when I use the full file path it doesn't throw an error and works OK.

When I use the WP function `get_theme_file_uri` inside the href attribute, it loads the font but shows errors in the console and in Chrome's Lighthouse audit. The code I'm using in the href attribute is:

`href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/fonts/alaska.ttf') ?> );"`

The file loads all OK but it questions whether I'm suing the `as` attribute in the console and in Chrome's Lighthouse audit asks if I'm using the `crossorigin` attribute correctly. I'm am using both of those attributes like this:

`<link rel="preload" href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/fonts/alaska.ttf') ?> );" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">`

My question is, is there a WP method that can be used in the head section for getting theme files that would be more appropriate than this. For obvious reasons I don't want to be putting the full file path in themes I'm making and then have to change this when a site is uploaded from a localhost environment.

**The Error Messages I Get Are:**

*Console*

The resource http://localhost:8888/inset/wp-content/themes/inset/fonts/alaska.ttf%20); was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

*Chrome Lighthouse Audit*

Warnings: A preload `<link>` was found for "http://localhost:8888/inset/wp-content/themes/inset/fonts/alaska.ttf" but was not used by the browser. Check that you are using the `crossorigin` attribute properly.

I get these error messages on both the localhost and live site, with no further info/explanation.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything wrong with `get_theme_file_uri()`. It will just return the full URL (rather than a path). What are the exact error messages? They can often be expanded to show more information. What does that say?

Comment: hi @JacobPeattie I've amended the question to include the error messages I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have these characters in the href that shouldn't be there:  `);` At the end.

```
href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/fonts/alaska.ttf') ?> );"
```

It should be

```
href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/fonts/alaska.ttf'); ?>"
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob. It was driving me round the bend.